# writing a custom comparer for linq groupby

Tags: linq, iequalitycomparer

Again this sample is a very simplified version of my actual problem involving a custom comparer for linq grouping. What have I done wrong?

The code below produces the result below
(1.2, 0),
(4.1, 0), (4.1, 0),
(1.1, 0),

however I was expecting the following since 1.1 and 1.2 are < 1.0 apart.
(1.2, 0), (1.1, 0),
(4.1, 0), (4.1, 0),

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Point> points = new List<Point> { 
            new Point(1.1, 0.0)
            , new Point(4.1, 0.0) 
            , new Point(1.2, 0.0)
            , new Point(4.1, 0.0)
        };

        foreach (var group in points.GroupBy(p => p, new PointComparer()))
        {
            foreach (var num in group)
                Console.Write(num.ToString() + ", ");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return Math.Abs(a.X - b.X) < 1.0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point point)
    {
        return point.X.GetHashCode()
            ^ point.Y.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public Point(double p1, double p2)
    {
        X = p1;
        Y = p2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "(" + X + ", " + Y + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use group by as a solution to cluster points. One reason is that GetHashcode must return the same hash for items that are equal.

Comment: I know it's not been done here, but one thing to beware of is: don't use `PointComparer.Default` instead of `new PointComparer()` - in spite of what the documentation says, it doesn't create a new `PointComparer` and instead creates an `ObjectEqualityComparer\`1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The grouping algorithm (and I think all LINQ methods) using an equality comparer always first compares hash codes and only executes `Equals` if two hash codes are equal. You can see that if you add tracing statements in the equality comparer:

```
class PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point a, Point b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Equals: point {0} - point {1}", a, b);
        return Math.Abs(a.X - b.X) < 1.0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point point)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HashCode: {0}", point);
        return point.X.GetHashCode()
            ^ point.Y.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```sql
HashCode: (1.1, 0)
HashCode: (4.1, 0)
HashCode: (1.2, 0)
HashCode: (4.1, 0)
Equals: point (4.1, 0) - point (4.1, 0)
(1.1, 0), 
(4.1, 0), (4.1, 0), 
(1.2, 0),
```

Only for the two points with equal hash codes `Equals` was executed.

Now you could trick the comparison by always returning `0` as hash code. If you do that, the output will be:

```sql
HashCode: (1.1, 0)
HashCode: (4.1, 0)
Equals: point (1.1, 0) - point (4.1, 0)
HashCode: (1.2, 0)
Equals: point (4.1, 0) - point (1.2, 0)
Equals: point (1.1, 0) - point (1.2, 0)
HashCode: (4.1, 0)
Equals: point (4.1, 0) - point (4.1, 0)
(1.1, 0), (1.2, 0), 
(4.1, 0), (4.1, 0),
```

Now for each pair `Equals` was executed, and you've got your grouping.

But...

What is "equal"? If you add another point `(2.1, 0.0)`, which points do you want in one group? Using the symbol `≈` for the fuzzy equality, we have -

```sql
1.1 ≈ 1.2
1.2 ≈ 2.1
```

but

```sql
1.1 !≈ 2.1
```

This means that `1.1` and `2.1` will never be in one group (their `Equals` never passes) and that *it depends on the order of the points* whether `1.1` or `2.1` are grouped with `1.2`.

So you're on a slippery slope here. Clustering points by proximity is far from trivial. You're entering the realm of [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Comment: This will take some thought. I tried your suggestion of always returning hash code 0 and with my actual data (not in the sample) it works well enough. I'll have to analyze where it might fail.

Comment: One way to get some kind of regularity (predictable results) is to always group points ordered the same way before grouping (for instance X first, then Y).

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget the effects of `GetHashCode`. There is an expectation that `GetHashCode` will always return the same value for any two objects for each `Equals` would return true. If you fail to meet that expectation, you'll get unexpected results.

Specifically, `GroupBy` probably uses something like a hash table to allow it to group items together without having to compare every item with every other item. If `GetHashCode` returns a value that doesn't end up putting two objects into the same bucket of the hash table, it'll assume that they're not equal, and will never try to call `Equals` on them.

You will find, as you try to figure out a correct implementation for `GetHashCode` that there's a fundamental problem with how you're trying to group your objects. What would you expect if you had points with x-values of `1.0`, `1.6`, and `2.2`? `1.0` and `2.2` are too far from one another to fall into the same group, but `1.6` is close enough to both other points that it should be in the same group with them. So your `Equals` method breaks the [Transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) property of equality:

> whenever A = B and B = C, then also A = C

If you're trying to do cluster grouping, you're going to need to use a more different data structure and algorithm. If you're just trying to normalize the points' locations somewhat, you might be able to just say `points.GroupBy(p => (int)p.X)` and avoid the equality comparer entirely.

Comment: Thata is exactly what I'm seeing, my GetHasCode has a significant impact on this problem. Any change I've made to it results in change in my output. What should my GetHashCode method look like?

Comment: @DustyB: See my updated answer. Your current definition for what makes two items "equal" is untenable. You have to come up with a more concrete idea of what you're trying to group items by, or use a different data structure and algorithm that's based on clustering rather than equality.

Comment: My actual problem uses 3D points and I want to cluster them such that points within 10 units and on the same plane group together. Is it feasible to do that with a custom comparer?

Comment: @DustyB: Not reliably. If point A and B are within 10 units of each other, and B and C are within 10 units of each other, but A is not within 10 units of C, then should they all be in a group together or not? No matter how you answer that question, any grouping algorithm you choose based purely on *equality* is going to fail to produce your desired output under some circumstances.