# GroupBy of List<double> with tolerance doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about `Groupby` of C#.

I made a `List` like shown below:

```
List<double> testList = new List<double>();

testList.Add(1);    
testList.Add(2.1);  
testList.Add(2.0);  
testList.Add(3.0);  
testList.Add(3.1);  
testList.Add(3.2);  
testList.Add(4.2);
```

I'd like to group these number list like this:

```
group 1 => 1  
group 2 => 2.1 , 2.0  
group 3 => 3.0 , 3.1 , 3.2  
group 4 => 4.2
```

so, I wrote code like this:

```
var testListGroup = testList.GroupBy(ele => ele, new DoubleEqualityComparer(0.5));
```

`DoubleEqualityComparer` definition is like this:

```
public class DoubleEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<double>
{
    private double tol = 0;

    public DoubleEqualityComparer(double Tol)
    {
        tol = Tol;
    }

    public bool Equals(double d1,double d2)
    {
        return EQ(d1,d2, tol);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double d)
    {
        return d.GetHashCode();
    }
    public bool EQ(double dbl, double compareDbl, double tolerance)
    {
        return Math.Abs(dbl - compareDbl) < tolerance;
    }
}
```

Yet the `GroupBy` clause doesn't work like the this:

```
group 1 => 1  
group 2 => 2.1
group 3 => 2.0  
group 4 => 3.0
group 5 => 3.1
group 6 => 3.2
group 7 => 4.2
```

I don't know what the problem is. Please let me know if there is problem, and solutions.

Comment: What is EQ operator here ?

Comment: sorry for that, I editted this code.

Comment: You need to set the "Center" of your tolerance.

Comment: In addition to what Fruchtzwerg mentions: what should happen with `1.9`? I assume it should be put into group 2, shouldn´t it?

Comment: you're right that 1.9 should be group 2

Answer (score 3):

use simple [Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx) to get lower range of the number so that 5.8 should not be treated as 6.

```
List<double> testList = new List<double>();

testList.Add(1);
testList.Add(2.1);
testList.Add(2.0);
testList.Add(3.0);
testList.Add(3.1);
testList.Add(3.2);
testList.Add(4.2);
testList.Add(5.8);
testList.Add(5.5);

var testListGroup = testList.GroupBy(s => Math.Floor(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: This will allways round downwards, thus `5.8` and `5.5` get grouped into the same group as `5.0`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: That's what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger It matches his results with the given test data, but `5.91 is within `0.5` of `4.2`, not of `3.2`, so looking at OP's original equality comparer it doesn't look like this would match the original intent.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetHashCode` method should return the same value for numbers, that should be "equal".

EqualityComparer works in two steps:

1. Checked `GetHashCode` if the value with this hash code was not
   processed yet, then this value gets into new single group
2. If value with this hash code was obtained - then checkinq result of
   `Equals` method. If it is true - adding current element to existing group, else adding it to new group.

In your case every `double` returns the different hash codes, so method `Equals` does not called.

So, if you do not care about processing time, you can simple return constant value in `GetHashCode` method as @FirstCall suggested. And if you care about it, I recommend to modify your method as follows:

```
public int GetHashCode(double d)
{
    return Math.Round(d).GetHashCode();
}
```

`Math.Round` should correctly work for tolerance = 0.5, for another tolerance values you should improve this.

I recommend you to read [this blog post](http://blog.alex-turok.com/2013/03/c-linq-and-iequalitycomparer.html) to get familiar with `IEqualityComparer` and `Linq`.

The simplest way with less amount of code is always return the constant value from the `GetHashCode` - it will work for any tolerance value, but, as I wrote, it is quite inefficient solution on large amounts of data.

Comment: You mean that GetHashCode() function has problem,right?

Comment: @kdm yes, this is exactly what I mean. If every record will return different hash code, as in your original post, `Equals` will not be executed

Answer (score 1):

You can group by using below code sample,

```
var list = testList.GroupBy(s => Convert.ToInt32(s) ).Select(group => new { Key = group.Key, Elements = group.ToList() });

//OutPut
//group 1 => 1  
//group 2 => 2.1 , 2  
//group 3 => 3 , 3.1 , 3.2  
//group 4 => 4.2
```

Explanation of the code,
When we apply `GroupBy` for a list which have only a single data column,It groups by looking same content. For an example think you have string list (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo1, foo1, foo2). So then it groups into three separate group leading by foo1, foo2 and foo3.

But in this scenario you can't find any same content(1.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.1,3.2...)So what we should do is bring them as a same content. When we convert them to `int` then it gives (1,2,2,2,3,3...). Then we can easily group it.

Comment: Select is not even required.

Comment: Yes of course. @StefanSteinegger. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It will give false positive results, if OP will want to run it on another set of numbers: (1.0, 1.5, 2.5) => ([1.0], [1.5,2.5]) as `Convert.ToInt32` returns the nearest even number if the value on halfway between two whole numbers. 1.5 => 2.0, 2.5 => 2.0.

Comment: @A.T. basically to group we need to have same content like( foo1, foo2, foo3, foo1, foo2, foo2). Then we can do it easily and it creates 3 groups. But in this scenario we only have different values(2.0,2.1,3.1,3.2...). Therefor we should bring it to same group of content. By converting it to int it gives (1,2,2,3,3,3). The we can group. it.

Comment: @codelahiru nice, it would be better if you add same explanation to the answer. It will help you to gain more votes.

Answer (score 1):

In these types of situations, the debugger is your friend. Put a break point on the `Equals` method. You will notice that the `Equals` method of your `DoubleEqualityComparer` class is not getting hit.

Linq extension methods rely on `GetHashCode` for equality comparisons. Since the `GetHashCode` method is not returning equivalent hashes for the doubles in your list, the `Equals` method is not getting called.

Each `GetHashCode` method should be atomic in execution and should return the same int value for any two equal comparisons.

This is one working example, though it is not necessarily recommended depending on your usage of this comparer.

```
public int GetHashCode(double d)
{
     return 1;
}
```

Comment: In the case of using single `IEqualityComparer` for different values of tolerance it is the best way for small amounts of data.

Comment: Your answer is good. I solved this problem with your advice. I'm happy to solve this problem. Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here is discussing what is wrong with your code, but you may actually have a worse problem than that.

If you truly want to group with a tolerance like your title says, rather than group by integer part like these answers assume (and your test data supports), this isn't supported by `GroupBy`.

`GroupBy` demands an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) - your equality comparer must establish that

- `x == x` for all `x`
- if `x == y`, `y == x` for all `x` and `y`
- if `x == y` and `y == z`, `x == z` for all `x`, `y` and `z`

"Within 0.5 of each other" matches the first two points, but not the third. 0 is close so 0.4, and 0.4 is close to 0.8, but 0 is not close to 0.8. Given an input of 0, 0.4 and 0.8, what groups would you expect?

Comment: True, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37733773/861716). This should probably be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Good spot, I'd agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your implementation of `GetHashCode` which must return equal values for everything you consider to be equal. So for two different values `d1` and `d2` that should go to the same group the method should return the same hash-code. To do so round the given number to the nearest intereger and compute its hashcode afterwards:

```
public int GetHashCode(double d)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(d).GetHashCode();
}
```

Right *after* that hashcode is calculated the actual `Equal`-check is done. In your current case the hash-values returned by `GetHashCode` are different, thus `Equals` won´t be executed at all.